# Finding the exponent of a number which is a multiple of a large number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $\frac{36^x}{3^{11}}$ is an integer, what is the smallest possible integer value of $x$? I'd like to know the approach to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $36^x=9^x \times 4^x=3^{2x}\times 4^x$.

Comment: Gosh this is so embarrassing. I had already come to this point! But didn't know how to proceed from here. I do know that if 36^x is a multiple of 3^11, the latter has to in the prime factorization of numerator. Could you give me one more hint or an approach?

Comment: In order for $3^{11}$ to divide the expression in the hint, we need $2x\ge 11$. So we want $x\ge 5.5$. But $x$ is supposed to be an integer, and the smallest one $\ge 5.5$ is $6$.

Comment: And no need to be embarrassed: this is how one learns.

Comment: Ah, there it is! I got confused by the other component, i.e. 4^x Frankly, still I'm not sure why that is insignificant to the solution. In cases like this should we always consider the largest exponent? (btw, many thanks for your solution :) )

Comment: The component $4^x$ has no $3$'s in its prime factorization, so its presence or absence is irrelevant to the divisibility question. Maybe I should have done a complete prime power factorization of the top as $3^{2x}\times 2^{2x}$, and it would have been clearer.

Comment: This is insanely beautiful, esp for a guy who has just started to go deep into fundamentals. Again, many thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome. Prime power factorization can be useful for divisibility, gcd, lcm questions.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$\frac{(36)^x}{3^{11}}=\frac{3^{2x}(4)^{x}}{3^{11}}=3^{2x-11}(4)^{x}.$$